# Using a variable in coded date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pull all data entries that are within a userform selected month and year.  I can get the code to run fine when I hard code the year but I want the year to come off of a text box. I converted the `Textbox` value to an integer using `Cint()` and dim'd it to "Year" in my if statement. I can get it to work if I write `Cdate("3/1/2016")`, but I want see if there is a way to run it like: `Cdate("3/1/Year")`. I tried it this way and get a typematch error on the Cdate  Im pretty new to VBA so excuse my stupidity.

Ignore the "Month" variable I was just using that to put a stop on the code and step it through to see if it would enter my if statement.

Thanks in advance.

**My Code**

```
Private Sub OKBtn_Click()

Dim Sales As Range
Dim Year As Integer
Dim Month As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Year = CInt(YearText.Value)    
Set Sales = Worksheets("Sales").Range("A4")    

i = 0
If Sales.Offset(i, 1).Value >= CDate("3/1/2016") And Sales.Offset(i, 1).Value <= CDate(" 3/31/2016 ") Then
    Month = 1
End If
```

Comment: try the code below and see if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `CDate` to work, you need to seperate the stings inside the brackets to 2 parts

1.The constant, in your case "3/1/".

2.And the variable, `CInt(YearText.Value)`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OKBtn_Click()

Dim DDate As Date
DDate = CDate("3/1/" & CInt(YearText.Value))

' for debug only
MsgBox "Date entered is :" & DDate

End Sub
```

Comment: @jnal you're welcome, please mark as answer (bu putting a little **V** next to my answer)